# Are there any videochat web applications that use the Pusher API to handle communication between user's sockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, socket.io, pusher, videochat

I plan on using the Pusher API for a videochat web application that I am building so I am interested in seeing the different ways the Pusher API can be used to handle connecting users, disconnecting users, etc. I am familiar with socket.io so advice on how to transition to the Pusher API would be greatly appreciated.

Recommendations to github projects would also be greatly appreciated.
+1 RubyonRails Projects

http://pusher.com/

Answer (score 1):

Pusher offers [presence](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels) which are used for forum-like functionality:

- A user subscribing to a channel and getting a list of the other users on the channel
- A notification when a user leaves the channel
- A notification when a user joins the channel

You can get this information on the client (JavaScript, Mobile etc.) and also on the server via [WebHooks](http://pusher.com/docs/webhooks).

- Pusher presence demo: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-presence-demo